# Fijar elemento en un scroll

Tags: css

Quisiera saber como le puedo asignar una propiedad a un boton para que aldarle click ese elemento se mantenga fijo en la parte superior del scroll

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Eso lo puedes lograr usando en css position:sticky;. Desafortunadamente tu pregunta está mal formulada y carece de un ejemplo mínimo verificable, por tanto no puedo ilustrarte como funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes fijar un elemento scroll utilizando la función sticky:

Te invito a  que revises esta pagina: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/sticky-positioning-with-nothing-but-css--cms-24042

**sticky** Funciona de manera similar al posicionamiento relativo, en cuanto que no elimina ningún elemento del flujo del documento. En otras palabras, un elemento "sticky" no afecta a la posición de sus elementos adyacentes, y no hunde su elemento padre.

Establecemos la posición del #sidebar a sticky y al mismo tiempo top: 10px. La propiedad top es requerida y especifica la distancia desde el borde superior del área de visualización de la página.

```
#sidebar

{ position: -webkit-sticky;  // required for Safari

position: sticky;

top: 0; // required as well.
```

Ya conforme desplacemos la página, cuando la distancia del sidebar al borde superior alcance 0, el sidebar debería quedar fijo, proporcionándonos de manera efectiva una posición fija. En otras palabras, el valor sticky es una especie de híbrido entre el posicionamiento relativo (relative) y fijo (fixed).

Comment: Saludos @GetsemaniCastillo, antes de responder a una publicación asegúrate siempre de que se ajuste a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), no necesariamente todas las preguntas deben ser respondidas ya que muchas "como ésta" carecen de información como para responderla de forma correcta y lo mas seguro es que terminen cerradas. ;)